# how to refresh a page in visual studio?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i have created a windows phone application. In each page i have given a back button using "NavigationService.GoBack()" command. i want that when the back button is pressed the previous page to which it navigate the whole code of that page must again be executed.

Comment: Why do you want to refresh the page

Comment: the data which i updated, to save score in the windows phone app it is not reflected in the previous page which store the list immediately when i am pressing the back button.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to take a look on how the MVVM works. If you have one Observable Collection that is for example bound to a list Box on Page_1 and an edit Screen on Page_2 you can directly edit the Data that is displayed on Page_1 on Page_2. Via NotifyPropertyChanged you can then inform the UI that there was a change in the data and the View should be updated automatically.

Comment: can you solve this problem with MVVM- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512033/storing-and-getting-data-in-windows-phone-app-and-using-navigationservice-goback

Comment: Yes of course. I can try to build up a sample for you this evening. I am not sure tough if I find time as I am pretty packed with work at the moment. I will add the solution file to the other post then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're relying the user pressing the hardware back button you shouldn't have to call `GoBack()` yourself.

To refresh a page when the user navigates back to it you can use the following in your page (and add the refresh code as appropriate):

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        // Do your refreshing here
    }
}
```